# How to resolve these promise chaining?

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to write 2 routes for my node app.
1 route is to return single item and 1 route is for array list.

The routes are like these.

```
router
  .route("/:income_id")
  .get((req, res) => {
      Income.findById(req.params.income_id)
        .populate("services.service_id")
        .then((income) => {
          return filterIncomeFunc(income);
        })
        .then((result) => {
          return res.status(200).json(result);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          res.status(404).json({ msg: "Income not Found" });
        });
  });


 router
      .route("/")
      .get((req, res) => {
          Income.find({})
            .populate("services.service_id")
            .then((income) => { 
             //problem here
              return filterArrayIncome(income);
            })
            .then((result) => {
             console.log('======================');
             console.log(result);
             console.log('======================');
              return res.status(200).json(result);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              res.status(404).json({ msg: "Income not Found" });
            });
      });
```

Since I need to filter 2 of these i write 2 helper array named `filterArrayIncome` & `filterIncomeFunc`

I code works for single item but the array function is not working,

Here are my code for filtering

```
const filterIncomeFunc = (income) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let filteredIncome = {};
    filteredIncome.services = income.services.map((service) => {
      return {
        service_name: service.service_id.service_name,
        price: service.price,
      };
    });
    filteredIncome.total_amount = income.total_amount;
    resolve(filteredIncome);
  });
};

const filterArrayIncome = (incomeArray) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let filteredIncome = incomeArray.map((eachIncome) => {
     return filterIncomeFunc(eachIncome);
    });
    resolve(filteredIncome);
  });
};
```

Since i want dry code i am using `filterIncomeFunc` inside the `filterArrayIncome`

Inside the filterArrayIncome the console.log result is like this.

```
======================
[
  Promise {
    {
      services: [Array],
      total_amount: 18000
    }
  },
  Promise {
    {
      
      services: [Array],
      total_amount: 18000
    }
  },
]
======================
```

Y these are returning promises. I already resolve inside the `filterArrayIncome` func

Comment: Don't return promises from those filter functions. It doesn't make any sense to do so.

Comment: @Khant added an answer by doing slight update in your code, let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use non-promises in promise chains.

```
Promise.resolve('a').then(() => 'b');
```

resolves to "b";

Your filter functions don't need to return promises, just have them return the values.

It makes no sense for them to return promises because they have everything they need to operate synchronously anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrapped the code through promised which were not asynchronous so basically now you have to get the actual value resolved by that promise, so to get the result, you can use async-await for less work now, below is your updated code

```
router
  .route("/:income_id")
  .get((req, res) => {
      Income.findById(req.params.income_id)
        .populate("services.service_id")
        .then(async (income) => {
          return await Promise.all(await filterArrayIncome(income));
        })
        .then((result) => {
          return res.status(200).json(result);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          res.status(404).json({ msg: "Income not Found" });
        });
  });


 router
      .route("/")
      .get((req, res) => {
          Income.find({})
            .populate("services.service_id")
            .then(async (income) => { 
             //problem here
              return await Promise.all(await filterArrayIncome(income));
            })
            .then((result) => {
             console.log('======================');
             console.log(result);
             console.log('======================');
              return res.status(200).json(result);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              res.status(404).json({ msg: "Income not Found" });
            });
      });
```

Comment: "*You have wrapped the code through promised which were not asynchronous*" - indeed. "*so basically now you have to get the actual value in that promise*" - no, that's the wrong conclusion

Comment: @mss The problem lies in the filter functions bro. I am returning the promise which is `no sense` as they mentioned

Comment: @khant yes, but  I wrote in my answer that for now, you can get away by  adding await just before returning to the next then where you send back the response, try this it should work

Comment: @mss I was not complaining about promise terminology. It's just the wrong solution to slap an `await` on it (and it doesn't even work here, `return await` is pointless, the `await` would need to be in a different location).

Comment: @mss not working  i got the same  wrong result. `If you got time try reproducing these prob and try solving these will help`

Comment: @Khant can you try the updated code one last time

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
const filterArrayIncome = (incomeArray) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let filteredIncome = incomeArray.map((eachIncome) => {
     return filterIncomeFunc(eachIncome);
    });
    resolve(filteredIncome); // this line is unreachable due to the return statement above.
  });
};
```

Returning a promise from a promise runs the executor of the promise and returns that settled promise, however doesn't return the settled value. Like the answer above said, there's no need for the use of promise here. But if you encounter a problem like this where you must return promises, you could do:

```
const filterArrayIncome = (incomeArray) => {
  return Promise.All(incomeArray.map((eachIncome) => {
     //SideNote : You'd wanna use a promise if the task you do inside this was asynchronous, which in your case is not.
     return filterIncomeFunc(eachIncome); 
    });
  );
}
```

Then it'd work as you'd expect. An array of resolved values of all promises returned by filterIncomeFunc would be received in the 'then' handler of your code. Or you could also try async...await like so:

```
const filterArrayIncome = async (incomeArray) => {
  return await Promise.All(incomeArray.map((eachIncome) => {
     return filterIncomeFunc(eachIncome); 
    });
  );
}
```

It also works the same way.